# Using window.URL.createObject in chrome intermittently failing when downloading multiple files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, base64

**The crux of the question:** I am consecutively downloading 2 files in javascript and chrome will intermittently switch between downloading one file or both. The setting to download multiple files automatically is activated.

**The details:**
For an internal app I am maintaining, there is a routine that retrieves two sets of base64 strings from an API. This app is only run in the latest version of google chrome but on both windows 8, 10 and the latest version of OSX.

The front end then decodes these strings into a data blob and then decodes the blobs into 2 csv's and downloads them.

The Web API I am using to download the files is the `createObjectURL()`, assuming the base64 is decoded correctly into a blob (which it is as this is used in multiple other instances) the function to download a file is as follows:

```
function downloadBlob (blob, filename, extension) {
    var a = window.document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = filename + '.' + extension;
    // Append anchor to body.
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    // Remove anchor from body
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Again this is used in multiple instances and has worked without a hitch.

So an AJAX request is made to the API to retrieve the two base64 strings, the success callback is essentially:

```
Function success (b64A, b64B) {
    var csvA = b64toBlob(b64A, 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
    downloadBlob(csvA, 'filename', 'csv');
    var csvB = b64toBlob(b64B, 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
    downloadBlob(csvB, 'filename', 'csv');
}
```

As you can see the downloads are executed consecutively. This has been tested across both chrome in windows 8 and chrome on OSX and both seem to intermittently download both files. Most of the time they only download the latter file.

I'm a bit confused as to why this was happening and was wondering if this is an issue with my code or some niche glitchy behaviour in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Chrome or intended behaviour however I managed to solve this by wrapping the second `downloadBlob()` in a setTimeout of 200ms:

```
Function success (b64A, b64B) {
  var csvA = b64toBlob(b64A, 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
  downloadBlob(csvA, 'filename', 'csv');
  setTimeout(function() {
    var csvB = b64toBlob(b64B, 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
    downloadBlob(csvB, 'filename', 'csv');
  }, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using HTML code and jquery to download multiple files but a few days ago i can download just the latest file.

I think now is blocked by Chrome.